# Need to publish site on IIS

Tags: tomcat, iis

My application is running on Apache Tomcat on application server (OS Windows Server 2016, XX.10.15.13) I want to publish this application from the Web server (OS Windows Server 2016, XX.10.70.5). How can I configure network traffic through web server to App server to reach tomcat where the application is hosted?

Comment: Apache documentation is the best source for an install like this: https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing Make the second server a reverse proxy.